# How can I find out what a Terminal command will do before I run it?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, command-line

If I run into a Terminal command here in StackExchange or elsewhere on the Internet, how can I easily understand what this command will do so that I can make sure it's safe before I run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a great online tool called [ExplainShell](https://explainshell.com) that will break down the command into its individual parts and explain what each part does.

For example, see [this page](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+add-apt-repository+--remove+%27deb+%5Barch%3Damd64%5D+https%3A%2F%2Fpackages.elementary.io%2Fappcenter+xenial+main%27) which explains the following command:

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial main'`

Comment: Didn't know that ExplainShell exists. Thanks for this